# Unable to access certain websites on Ubuntu (Facebook, Google, Twitter, etcs)

Tags: internet

I have a dual-boot machine. The internet is perfectly fine when I use Windows; I can access all websites normally.

However, when I change to Ubuntu, I can no longer access Facebook, Twitter, YouTube, etc.

What is going on? What should I do to get this fixed?

Edit :

My DNS : 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

From `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:46:5d:3f:f5:09  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:202999 (202.9 KB)  TX bytes:202999 (202.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:85:de:a4:e4:7d  
          inet addr:192.168.0.102  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::de85:deff:fea4:e47d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7149295 (7.1 MB)  TX bytes:1679041 (1.6 MB)
```

From `ip addr`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:46:5d:3f:f5:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:85:de:a4:e4:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.102/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::de85:deff:fea4:e47d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can ping `www.google.com` (0% lost), but when i tried to ping `www.youtube.com`, only forever loading happened here :

`PING www.youtube.com (46.82.174.68) 56(84) bytes of data.`

When i run `nm-tool | tail -n 8` :

```
IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.102
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1
```

Please help me.

Comment: are you on a PPPoE connection??

Comment: @Meow Sorry what is that?im a beginner in networking. I just use a normal internet connection without proxy, etc

Comment: okay do you have a router or do you connedt directly to modem and what is your "ifconfig" output

Comment: Is it only few sites or all websites?? Also open a terminal using `CTRL+ALT+T` & type `ping google.com`, then see whether site is reachable. If you don't understand, you may [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/419373/edit) your question & post the output here.

Comment: @Meow its from a Wifi

Comment: Seems this is using WiFi. Can I also see the output for `nm-tool | tail -n 8` please. :)

Comment: try sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1450 and sudo ifconfig wlan0 mtu 1450 and then opening

Comment: @Meow Tried that, nothing happened :(

Comment: @Azker please see my edited question, its on the bottom

Comment: @Meow ITS WORKING NOw! I need to restart my modem after i changed the mtu to 1450. Could you kindly tell me what i did by changing the mtu to 1450? Is it somehow dangerous? Thanks :D

Comment: @Meow Please answer my question so i can upvote it. Thanks

Comment: its not permanent once you restart your pc it'll be back to same problem and mtu is max packet size for it to be permanent you need to change etc/network/interfaces

Comment: it because some website servers use windows while some use linux and windows servers cant accept large packet sizes so the site will be forever loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1450 
 sudo ifconfig wlan0 mtu 1450
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Could you kindly tell me how to make this change permanently?

Comment: add the line mtu 1450 at the end of file etc/network/interfaces

Comment: gksu gedit etc/network/interfaces